# How does the constant value auto type work in golang?

Tags: go, constants

Here is the code snippet:

```
a := 40
f := float64(a/100.0)
fmt.Println("Hello, playground", f)
```

`f=0`, why?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec: Constants:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

> An untyped constant has a *default type* which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required, for instance, in a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) such as `i := 0` where there is no explicit type. The default type of an untyped constant is `bool`, `rune`, `int`, `float64`, `complex128` or `string` respectively, depending on whether it is a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

`a := 40` is a short variable declaration, the untyped integer constant `40` has a default type `int`, so `a` will be of type `int`.

In `a/100.0` since `a` is of type `int` and `100.0` is representable by an integer, it will take the type of `int`, and `a/100.0` will be an integer division, resulting in `0`.

This `0` `int` value will be then converted to `float64`.

Note that if you would change the first line to:

```
a := 40.0
```

Then the output would be `0.4` because the `40.0` is an untyped floating point literal and so it has a default type of `float64`. So `a` will be of type `float64`, and `a/100.0` will be a floating-point division, resulting in `0.4`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p3GMqdDV8wa).

You would get the same result if you'd use a *typed* constant, because here no default type is used, `float64(40)` is a typed constant, obviously of type `float64` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BTSCyDyW7_G)):

```
a := float64(40)
```

See [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Comment: I see. Since the type of variable 'a' is fixed in order for the expression to compile the constant 100.0 has to be integer.  I confirmed this by changing  100.0 to 100.1 and it won't compile. My intention for augmenting 'a' to be float is wrong from the beginning.

Comment: @user1206899 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here default type for `a` is `int` since you use `a:=40` and but `100.0` is just a constant so no auto-detect of type for variable.
So `a/100.0` consider as integer division and which result is `0` which means `f := float64(0)` executed

**Case Analysis**

If you set `100.0` in a variable.

```
a := 40
b := 100.0
f := float64(a/b)
```

Then `b` is a `float64` type. So you get error like

```
invalid operation: a / b (mismatched types int and float64)
```

Because you are trying to do divide operation with two different type

And if type cast `a` into `float64()` then it works

```
a := 40
b := 100.0
f := float64(a)/b
```

So, here both variable is `float64` type in divide operation.

Now, as we cast `a` into float64 then in divide operation we can directly use `100.0` without variable.

```
a := 40
f := float64(a)/100.0
```